# Constraints programmatically do not work the same way as constraints in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

I'm trying to use auto layout programmatically to make my custom view adapt its size when bounds change. 
What I'm trying to achieve:
1) make the view be as large as possible on the screen but keep the aspect ratio between its height and size 8/5
2) never go outside the safe area
3) always stay in the middle
When I use this set of constraints in storyboard everything works perfectly but when I do the same thing in code xcode breaks my height constraint (which I use for the aspect ratio for the view). I played with priorities but without success. What am I doing wrong?
Here's my code and the screenshot of my storyboard constraints:

[screenshot of storyboard constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Pkdj.png)

```
private func setupLayout () {

    playingCardView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    //makes the maxim width possible
    let playingCardViewWidthConstraint = playingCardView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 800)
    playingCardViewWidthConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250)
    playingCardViewWidthConstraint.identifier = "width"

    //for aspect ratio
    let playingCardViewHeightConstraint = playingCardView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: playingCardView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 8.0/5.0)
    playingCardViewHeightConstraint.identifier = "height"

    //make the view stay within bounds
    //add some padding top
    let playingCardTopConstraint = playingCardView.topAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: Constants.offsetFromTheEdge)

    //add some padding bottom
    let plaingCardViewBottomConstraint = playingCardView.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: Constants.offsetFromTheEdge)

    //add some padding leading
    let playingCardViewLeadingConstraint = playingCardView.leadingAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: Constants.offsetFromTheEdge)

    ////add some padding trailing
    let playingCardViewTrailingConstraint = playingCardView.trailingAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: Constants.offsetFromTheEdge)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        playingCardViewWidthConstraint,
        playingCardViewHeightConstraint,
        playingCardView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        playingCardView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        playingCardTopConstraint,
        playingCardViewBottomConstraint,
        playingCardViewLeadingConstraint,
        playingCardViewTrailingConstraint
            ])
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you examined either of your set-ups using Xcode's [view hierarchy debugging tool](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH9-SW2)?

Comment: @PaulPatterson Yes, I did. Xcode breaks my height constraint and adds a new one instead with 1.6 aspect ratio. The problem is that I'm just learning to program so there is a chance that I'm missing something important.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to constraints you need to think of 4 things

x => leading / trailing / left / right / centerX

y => top , bottom , centerY

width => static / proportional

height =>  static / proportional

I think here you trigger all possible conflicts , regardless of priorities

> you give the view a width of 800 and give it leading && trailing which for sure less than that , How To ??
>
> you give the view aspect ratio height and hook it's top and bottom , How To ??
>
> you give leading & trailing and give centerX , Why To ??
>
> you give top and bottom and give centerY , Why To ??

Don't add a constraint if it will not add any value

Comment: what I really don't understand is why it works when we add this set of constraints to storyboard with no errors? (I tool the logic from Standford University course) Why the same logic has different results?

Answer (score 0):

In your posted code...

You are missing a `y` in `let plaingCardViewBottomConstraint = ...`

Other than that, you are setting your Top and Bottom constraints to `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide` but you're setting your Leading and Trailing constraints to `layoutMarginsGuide`.

Change `view.layoutMarginsGuide` to `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide` and you should have what you expect.